# How to escape html tags ? in json retrived from php in phonegap android

Tags: php, android, ajax, json

I creating an app in which I'm  using php in server side.When an Ajax call is made its calling an php to retrieve the data from the table but the issue is some table contains html & special characters tags so i get an error in the Ajax :

```
05-31 00:59:07.670: D/CordovaLog(872): Server is not responding... Please try again: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
05-31 00:59:07.670: I/chromium(872): [INFO:CONSOLE(342)] "Server is not responding... Please try again: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: file:///android_asset/www/home.html (342)
```

can any tell how to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you may use `escapeHtml` which Returns an HTML escaped representation of the given plain text.
For more info see at [escapeHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#escapeHtml%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Or you may use `TextUtils.htmlEncode("your json tag")` to encode html.

**Edit**
As you are using **phonegap** so you may use `htmlencoding` is **PHP** also as

```
htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
```

For more information see at [htmlentities in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

To encode html in php and decode back in your app,you may refer this link
[Using PHP’s JSON encode and decode functions to handle data sent to and from your app](http://samcroft.co.uk/2014/php-json-encode-decode-functions-tutorial/)

Comment: can you give me an example the page link you provide is for native im developing the app in phonegap....

Comment: @NeeravShah to encode html in php see edited answer.

Comment: but if we encode json data in php how to decode it in the html page in phonegap.